# Fancybox does not display - Navigates to youtube instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, fancybox, preventdefault

I trying to add a fancybox pop up for a youtube video to the homepage of one of my sites. When I click on the video it fires the click function but instead of opening the fancybox window it redirects the page to the physical youtube video.

I have tried utilizing preventDefault, however when I do that I get a .fancybox is not a function exception.

I've done quite a bit of digging through different posts with similar issues but most of them are a few years old and the fixes don't seem to be effective in my situation.

Here are my script/style calls:

```
<script src="/shared_Gen/jQuery/FancyBox/v1.0/jquery.fancybox-1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/shared_Gen/jQuery/FancyBox/v1.0/fancy.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The on click/fancybox call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.fancybox").click(function (event) {

        $.fancybox({
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'title': this.title, // optional
            'width': 680, // or your size
            'height': 495,
            'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type': 'swf',
            'swf': {
                'wmode': 'transparent',
                'allowfullscreen': 'true'
            }
        }); // fancybox

        return false;
    });

});
```

The div and link:

```
<div id="video_player">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpyB7lF5fqk" class="fancybox">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/vpyB7lF5fqk/default.jpg" alt="YouTube" width="300" height="169" />
</a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I've spent far to much time on what should be an easy task...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what version of fancybox? anyways, try the embedded format `https://www.youtube.com/embed/vpyB7lF5fqk` and open it in `iframe` mode instead of `swf`... try also upgrading your fancybox version at least to 1.3.4

Comment: The version was the issue. Thank you for the help! Also sorry about the very late response I ended up with some time off of work and didn't get back to this until very recently.

Answer (score 0):

Try `event.preventDefault()` at the top of your callback function. I'm assuming you have an error somewhere (probably fancybox not being included correctly and not existing as a function on `$`) and the `return false` is never reached.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a.fancybox").click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    alert('Fancybox click handler fired!');

    $.fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'autoScale': false,
        'transitionIn': 'none',
        'transitionOut': 'none',
        'title': this.title, // optional
        'width': 680, // or your size
        'height': 495,
        'href': this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type': 'swf',
        'swf': {
            'wmode': 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen': 'true'
        }
    }); // fancybox

  });

});
```

I threw an alert message at the top of the function, just to make sure it is executing and should obviously be removed once confirmed.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance rsnorman. Doing this actually caused several other problems in the code however JFK was correct in his comment on my original post. After updating the version of my fancybox it worked just fine.